# Checking each data type in a list and to sum any numbers in the list and print them

Tags: python

I'm trying to check every data type in a list and if the list has a mix of data types then print out that the list is a mix and sum any numbers in the list. It should work for any list. Any ideas?
This is what I have so far.

```
a = ["cats",4,"n",2,"the",3,"house"]
total = 0
for i in a:
   if isinstance(i , int) and isinstance(i, str):
     total = total + i
     print "This list has a mix of data types"
     print total
   else:
```

Comment: This is a rather unfortunate situation to be in. Where did this list come from?

Comment: I made up the list, I'm trying to make it as random as possible.

Comment: This sort of thing is generally best avoided a priori in well-designed, real programs.

Comment: What a relief to hear that, considering I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = ["cats",4,"n",2,"the",3,"house"]
if len(set([type(i) for i in a])) > 1:
    print("Mixed types")
total = sum([i for i in a if type(i)==int or type(i)==float])
print(total)
```

This results in:

```
Mixed types
9
```

Comment: Nice, I was thinking of how to do the data type comparison in a list comprehension but `set()` completely escaped me.  That was nice and neat.

Comment: great! yes `set()` is surprisingly useful

Comment: `set()` is a super nice object here

Comment: @RoadRunner yes I could change it to `total = sum([i for i in a if type(i)==int or type(i)==float])`, but OP seemed to be interested in `int` and `str` types in his post

Answer (score 3):

I think you can remember for the first element of list, and then check if the remains element in the list is the same type of first element.

```
total = 0
first_type = type(a[0])
data_mixed = False
if isinstance(a[0], int):
    total += a[0]

if len(a) > 1:
    for i in a[1:]:
        if not isinstance(i, first_type):
            data_mixed = True
            print("This list has a mix of data types")
        if isinstance(i, int):
            total += i

if not data_mixed:
    print("not a mix of data types")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a try/except block:

```
a = ["cats",4,"n",2,"the",3,"house"]
total = 0
msg = None

for i in a:
    try:
        total += float(i)
    except ValueError:
        msg = 'This list has a mix of data types'

if msg:
    print(msg)
print(total)
```

Prints:

```
This list has a mix of data types
9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
a = ["cats",4,"n",2,"the",3,"house"]
data_types = []
total = 0
for i in a:
    if type(i) not in data_types:
        data_types.append(type(i))
    if isinstance(i, int):
        total += i
if len(data_types) > 1:
    print("List has a mix data type of: {0}".format(', '.join([str(i) for i in data_types])))
if total > 0:
    print("The total of integer in the list is: {0}".format(total))
```

**Output:**

```
List has a mix data type of: <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>
The total of integer in the list is: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def isMixedType(l):
    return any( type(l[i]) != type(l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1) )
```

Basic idea is to check is all the elements are of same time, if all of them are not of same type, then there must of at least one adjacent pair of elements in the list having  different datatypes. We can use `any` to check that. Advantage of using `any` is that it will stop checking at the first occurrence of truth.

```
def mixedTypeSum(l):
    numbers_only = ( x for x in l if isinstance(x,(int,float)))
    return sum(numbers_only)
```

You can use `isinstance` to check if an item belongs to a type or one of several types.  `isinstance(x, (type1,type2 )  )` returns true if x if of type 1 or type 2.

Then filter the numbers out and use `sum` function.

```
a = ["cats",4,"n",2,"the",3,"house"]

print(isMixedType(a))
#prints True

print(mixedTypeSum(a)) 
#prints 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `collections.defaultdict` is also another option:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def mixed_types(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)

    for x in lst:
        d[type(x)].append(x)

    if len(d) > 1:
        print("Mixed types")

    print(sum(d[int] + d[float]))
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> mixed_types(["cats",4,"n",2.0,"the",3,"house", 3.0])
Mixed types
12.0
>>> mixed_types(["cats",4,"n",2,"the",3,"house"])
Mixed types
9
>>> print(mixed_types([1, 2, 3]))
6
```